# More than one cell to be added in with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Running SQL in Vba, it is working and all is fine, but i would like to add more than one "With" as shown under, could someone please explain? Ive tried googling but i cant seem to find my answer or if there is another way to do this?

i would like to add "Postnr" from cell A3, "Ordrenr" from cell A5, "Sendersref" from cell A7.

or is it possible to get the listed from excel cells aswell? Like 
Postnr(tabel) from Cell A2 and Value from cell A3?(Would be the best solution).

```
...
sSQL = "SELECT top 1 *" & _   
        " FROM tklient" & _    
        " WHERE klient = ?;"    
Set rDest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

Set qt = rDest.Parent.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _   
    Source:=Array(Sconnect), Destination:=rDest).QueryTable

**With qt.Parameters.Add("klient", xlParamTypeVarChar)    
    .SetParam xlRange, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")    
    .RefreshOnChange = True    
End With**    
With qt    
    .CommandText = sSQL   
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql   
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True  
    .BackgroundQuery = False   
       .Refresh   
End With

Set qt = Nothing   
Set rDest = Nothing   
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to copy the existing `With` block and paste it right below?

Comment: Wow, that simple.. Thanks alot! :) but for my second question, is it possible to get the value "klient" from a excel cell aswell?

Comment: Is it not what you are already doing?

Comment: i am currently getting the value for "klient" but not the parameter for the tabel. So it would show up in the SQL ( Klient = 101010 ) But Klient is not from a excel cell since its in the VBA code. Pretty new to VBA so sorry if it seems like a stupid question :)

Comment: You are adding a parameter named `klient` to the query table. You are setting this parameter to take its value from the cell `A1` (so it will when you refresh). What do you want instead?

Comment: i would like to get the parameter named `klient` from a excel cell aswell if that is possible.

Comment: That is what is happening. What do you want instead?

Comment: `With qt.Parameters.Add(**"klient"**, xlParamTypeVarChar)    
    .SetParam xlRange, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")    
    .RefreshOnChange = True    
End With` This is getting the value for the parameter, i would like to get the parameter from a excel cell aswell. `With qt.Parameters.Add(**A2**, xlParamTypeVarChar)    
    .SetParam xlRange, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")    
    .RefreshOnChange = True    
End With`

Comment: So you want to take the *name* of the parameter from the sheet. That would be `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value`, but it would have worked just the same if you had put just `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")`. It does not make a difference though because when the SQL command distinguishes parameters by position, like it does here, the name of the parameter does not matter.

Comment: ah, Thanks for your time and help @GSerg.